# Remove entire IDs from the dataframe based on multiple conditions

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I want to remove the entire ids from the patient data set with multiple condition in which the record date equal to fvdate should be removed completely. my data set will look like

```
ID  Record date Disease  Fvdate
1   02-03-2012   0     02-03-2012
2   03-03-2013   1     03-03-2013
3   04-03-2014   0     04-03-2014
3   03-03-2015   1     03-03-2015
4   06-06-2016   1     02-03-2012
4   07-06-2017   1     03-03-2013
5   08-05-2018   1     04-03-2014
6   09-06-2019   0     03-03-2015
```

i want the output to be

```
ID  Record date Disease  Fvdate
1   02-03-2012   0    02-03-2012
2   03-03-2013   1    03-03-2013
4   06-06-2016   1    02-03-2012
4   07-06-2017   1    03-03-2013
5   08-05-2018   1    04-03-2014
6   09-06-2019   0    03-03-2015
```

Example input data:

```
d <- read.table(text = "
ID  Record_date Disease  Fvdate
1   02-03-2012   0     02-03-2012
2   03-03-2013   1     03-03-2013
3   04-03-2014   0     04-03-2014
3   03-03-2015   1     03-03-2015
4   06-06-2016   1     02-03-2012
4   07-06-2017   1     03-03-2013
5   08-05-2018   1     04-03-2014
6   09-06-2019   0     03-03-2015", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: I really don't understand what you want. You say that the rows are removed under  multiple conditions: the first one is that ```Record date``` is equal to ```fvdate```, I get that, but what is the second condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter on condition that dates are not the same **OR** number of rows per ID is 1:

```
library(dplyr)

d %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  filter(!Record_date == Fvdate | n() == 1)

#   ID Record_date Disease     Fvdate
# 1  1  02-03-2012       0 02-03-2012
# 2  2  03-03-2013       1 03-03-2013
# 3  4  06-06-2016       1 02-03-2012
# 4  4  07-06-2017       1 03-03-2013
# 5  5  08-05-2018       1 04-03-2014
# 6  6  09-06-2019       0 03-03-2015
```

Comment: I came up with something similar, but thought logic of OP was to have something like: `filter(!(Record_date == Fvdate & n() > 1))`

Comment: @Ben Thanks for the helping hand but it doesn't reflect to me as i needed.

Comment: @Matrix_32 I've reread the comments, and not sure what is working/not working. It might be helpful if you provide additional examples that demonstrate why the offered solutions don't work. Right now, the example just removes 2 rows (ID == 3). If you could, add some additional example rows where rows need to be removed, and our code does not remove them, or give example rows where the code removes them inappropriately. In short, additional positive and negative examples would help.

Comment: @zx8754 no it shows changes but doesnt answer my concept