# remove all ids if two condition met in R

Tags: r

I have set of patient ids with **record date** and **first-visit date** and **disease** status i want to remove all **patient ids** if they have equal **record date** and **first visit date**. My data set look like

```
p_id Record_date  fvdate     Disease
 12  02-03-2017  02-03-2017   1
 12  05-03-2017  02-03-2017   0
 12  03-04-2018  02-03-2017   1
 11  04-05-2016  05-06-2017   0
 13  18-06-2017  18-06-2017   1
 13  03-05-2018  18-06-2017   0      
 13  09-09-2019  18-06-2017   0
 14  09-12-2017  03-01-2018   1
```

OUTPUT I NEEDED

```
p_id  Record_date      fvdate     Disease
11    04-05-2016      05-06-2017    0
14    09-12-2017      03-01-2018    1
```

Thank you in Advance

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: How is this different from your previous question?  https://stackoverflow.com/q/60738468/680068

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can select groups where `first` `Record_date` is different than `fvdate` for that `p_id`.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(p_id) %>% filter(first(Record_date) != first(fvdate))

#  p_id Record_date fvdate     Disease
#  <int> <fct>       <fct>        <int>
#1    11 04-05-2016  05-06-2017       0
#2    14 09-12-2017  03-01-2018       1
```

Or :

```
df %>% group_by(p_id) %>% filter(!any(Record_date == first(fvdate)))
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(p_id = c(12L, 12L, 12L, 11L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 14L
), Record_date = c("02-03-2017", "05-03-2017", "03-04-2018", 
"04-05-2016", "18-06-2017", "03-05-2018", "09-09-2019", "09-12-2017"
), fvdate = c("02-03-2017", "02-03-2017", "02-03-2017", "05-06-2017", 
"18-06-2017", "18-06-2017", "18-06-2017", "03-01-2018"), Disease = c(1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: In case `first` is not the best logic, you could do `any(Record_date %in% fvdate)`, right?

Comment: yes, (assuming you meant `!any(Record_date %in% fvdate)`) another way of doing it. However, I think first visit date would be the same for a particular patient, so you can take any date in `fvdate` or all of them.

Comment: @Ronak Shah Thanks dude your second codes works as I expected and perfectly